# Amazon sdk dowload large zip file from s3 bucket in spring boot java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, gzip, aws-sdk

What I did was trying to download large data zip file from s3 bucket

```
        S3ObjectInputStream inputStreams = s3object.getObjectContent(); 
        File newFile = new File(zipFileTempLocation + File.separator + CommonConstant.FILE_NAME);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
        LOGGER.info("staring to write {}", newFile.toPath());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[5000];
        int le
        while ((len = gzipInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        gzipInputStream.close();
        String newFileURl = newFile.getAbsolutePath();
        Path path = Paths.get(url);
        return Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

}

when I trying to run my service it says out of heap memory error. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: can you please put the trace of exception ?

Comment: I guess this line causes the heap to use up `Files.readAllBytes(path)` since you try to read the large file at once into a java File Object which is propably to large. Include the stack trace to see where exactly it occurs

Comment: @zeg thanks for the advices. I have fixed this using chunks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58947904/6580933) answer and stream it so it's not loaded into memory.

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/downloadfile/**", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<S3ObjectInputStream> downloadFile(HttpServletRequest request) {
       //reads the content from S3 bucket and returns a S3ObjectInputStream
       S3Object object = publishAmazonS3.getObject("12345bucket", "/logs/file1.log");
       S3ObjectInputStream finalObject = object.getObjectContent();

        final StreamingResponseBody body = outputStream -> {
            int numberOfBytesToWrite = 0;
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            while ((numberOfBytesToWrite = finalObject.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                System.out.println("Writing some bytes..");
                outputStream.write(data, 0, numberOfBytesToWrite);
            }
            finalObject.close();
        };
        return new ResponseEntity<>(body, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```